# Create Html from React Component including Style

Tags: reactjs, ref

I have a simple react component in which using ref I am getting the div but I have to generate a html includes styling as well. So I can pass this html to PDF generation backend server.

```
pdfRef(elem){
        console.log(elem);
//<div><span>dataPDF</span> </div>

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div ref={(elem) => this.pdfRef(elem)} className="SomeCssClass">
                <span >dataPDF</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

[Edit]

When I try to print the div via ref, the elements are printed with class name. But when I send this string to pdf service, since only html element is sent and class name without the actual css , the pdf is generated without style.

is there any way to generate html with css as as string so further it can be send to pdf service. Hope the question is clear 
Any pointers?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you looking for, can you be a little precise ?

Answer (score -2):

The `server.js` script in react-dom lets you render a React component to static html string. You can require it in your code like:

```
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
```

Or using ES6 syntax:

```
import ReactDomServer from 'react-dom/server'
```

After this you can render your component to HTML string using the `ReactDomServer.renderToString` or `ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup` functions as follows:

```
const htmlStr = ReactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<MyComponent prop1={'value1'} />);
```

This looks almost exactly like `ReactDom.render`, except that it doesn't need the second parameter of dom node to render at, and the html string is returned. Additionally this method can be used on both client and server side. For your generate-pdf use case `renderToStaticMarkup` would suffice. If required check the documentation at following link for subtle difference between the two methods mentioned above: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html